# Will isolation level change during a database transaction?

Tags: c#, sql-server, isolation-level, database-deadlocks

In our C# application, we have not set isolation level, so i assume the default isolation level is going as Read Committed. However during a deadlock, we could see that lockmode of the application is

> isolationlevel="serializable (4)"

What it mean by serializable(4) ? Also will the isolation level auto-convert to some other during a transaction?

Comment: How are you viewing the transaction isolation level in the application during the deadlock?

Comment: No, the isolation level will not change on its own. Yes, you can change the isolation level in a transaction, either through an explicit `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL` or by applying a table hint in a `FROM` clause. But a more likely cause of an unexpected isolation level is getting a pooled connection that earlier had a serializable transaction: [the isolation level is not reset](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/243527/sp-reset-connection-doesnt-reset-isolation-level). If you want to be sure, always set it explicitly.

Comment: @RossBush, we got the deadlock logs from DBA which has list of processes and resources in deadlock

Comment: @JeroenMostert, I have gone through the link. That answered pretty much about the reason of surprise isolation levels. As it is fixed in SQL Server 2014, the only work around is to use explicit transactions

Answer (score 1):

For helping others, i am posting the solution we found. We were using transaction with help of **TransactionScope** with its default constructor. Its default isolation level is *serializable* which made the confusion. Now corrected it to use **Read Committed** as the isolation level explicitly.